# Installing XP Pro without disc on Dell Latitude D610?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, oem, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude D610 from my company that they gave me with XP Pro installed on it. I have an OEM key from Dell on a sticker on the computer. I'd like to get a fresh install of XP Pro in it for free.

I was wondering about a few things. First, if I find an iso online, does it need to be Dell specific to activate with my key, or would a standard XP Pro one work? I did not get a recovery disc of any sort with the system.

However, with a Dell desktop, I have an XP Home recovery CD. Would that potentially work to install and activate with my Pro key?

Comment: Ask your company for the disc.  Also, be sure to transfer the ownership:  http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/customercare/f/4674/t/19493046

Answer (score 0):

dell keys only work on dell windows cds / dell windows iso. you may be able to get a dell cd off ebay or off dell. You already have a dell license key. You can install windows from a regular windows cd but then you need a regular key not a dell key.

Answer (score 0):

**You need Windows XP Professional CD from Dell.**

Windows XP Home CD from Dell will not work with your key.

Windows XP Professional NOT from dell will not work too.

1. I guess this computer warranty expired, so you probably can't order recovery CD from Dell, but **you can buy CD on ebay**. I found one for $9.99.
2. If there is `c:\i386` directory on this computer - you can use these files to reinstall windows. Create bootable pendrive with some DOS and put i386 directory there. There should be setup.exe file - it is windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

**It's quite possible your PC still has the factory restore partition** - in which case, you do not need to 'find' an ISO online - you won't even need the key, actually.

Assuming you've backed up everything you want to keep, restart the PC and hold Ctrl+F11 as it reboots.

If you see the "***Dell PC Restore By Symantec***", you should be good to go, as this holds a disk image of the initial (i.e. factory) XP installation.

Select that option, and let it work its magic - this is fully automated, and doesn't require any input. (it may take a bit of time, but it is nevertheless faster than a manual re-installation).

**Please note:**

- If the disk was repartitioned at some point in its life, the restore partition may be gone.
- This is different from a 'recovery CD'.
- Once the fresh disk image is restored, you will have to follow through with a (long) session of drivers and Windows updates, as the OS reverts to the state it was whenever that computer shipped. Not a big price to pay for a nice clean install though.
- Any third-party software that wasn't part of the initial factory setup will have to be re-installed, obviously.
- It remains up to you to figure out if you can legally use this OEM license (possibly a Volume License, if you've got this out of a company pool) - See Billy_Bob comment to your initial question.